# How to send multiple requests to a server at few milliseconds of interval in C#

Tags: c#, asynchronous, timer, task-parallel-library

I have a code that looks like this:

```
public static async Task<Request> SendRequest(Client client, DateTime startTime, int offset)
{
    TimeSpan timeToWait = startTime - DateTime.UtcNow + TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(offset);
    await Task.Delay(timeToWait);
    Console.Write(offset);
    Request request = client.sendRequest();
}

async static public Task<Request> SendMultiple(Client client, DateTime startTime)
{
    var offsets = new[] { -15, -10 };
    offsets.ForEach(offset => tasks.Add(SendRequest(client, startTime, offset));
    Request[] result = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
```

The problem it seems, is that the prints show that:

```
08:59:59,985: -15
09:00:00,015: -10
```

So the first try was indeed, 15 milliseconds before 9AM. However, the second tried 15 milliseconds after 9AM instead of 10 milliseconds prior.

How could I ensure that those requests are being send exactly at the time I want, please?

I am using Ubuntu*

Comment: _How could I ensure that those requests are being send exactly at the time I want_: Don't use Windows and don't use _.NET_ or _.NET Framework_.

Comment: How exact do you need it to be? I doubt you'll get it to the millisecond. Windows is not a real-time OS and dotnet surely doesn't add real-time capabilities. To come close to best effort, easiest would be to use a scheduling lib/ framework...

Comment: Windows timers typically have a resolution of about 15 ms by default, so an offset of 10ms is just not gonna work. Also, just because the delay ended doesn't mean the OS will immediately run your process thread again. If you really need to do this with .net increasing the priority of your thread/process, and calling timeBeginPeriod(1) if you are on Windows, are your best bets. And even then you might not achieve your desired precision.

Comment: What time source does your computer use? Computer real time clocks are usually not that exact that you could sync them in a way to come close to an atomic clock. And that seems to be what you would need to make a request zk a different server at an exact time with millisecond precision.

Comment: I am using Ubuntu. What scheduling lib/ framework. could i use? And you say not use .NET. What else could be more performant then ? And so no clue what my laptop time source is using. The idea anyway, would be then to put it on an EC2

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to distribute the request accross threads instead ?

Comment: Sounds like you want to do a DDOS?

Comment: @NicolasREY you didn't answer *how precise* you want to be and *why*. That's VERY important. The general purpose schedulers of *any* OS don't guarantee millisecond accuracy. When such accuracy is required, all OSs use specialized multimedia or real-time schedulers. You *can* reduce the timer resolution of a system, like Chrome used to do, but that results in high power consumption, a common complaint with Chrome in the past. Increasing timer resolution doesn't fix the unavoidable skew either

Comment: @NicolasREY this has nothing to do with performance, .NET or scheduling libraries anyway - if the OS doesn't schedule your thread, it won't run. EC2 will try to put cores to sleep even more aggressively than your laptop too. If you use a general purpose OS scheduler for animations, they'll stutter. [Ubuntu Pro has a real-time kernel](https://ubuntu.com/blog/real-time-kernel-technical) but requires a subscription.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your best bet is to wait with a timer (`Task.Delay`) until a few milliseconds before the target time, and then wait the final milliseconds by spinning. In the example below the spinning duration is set to about 20 milliseconds:

```
DateTime targetTime = startTime + TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(offset);
TimeSpan timeToWait = targetTime - DateTime.UtcNow - TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(20);

if (timeToWait > TimeSpan.Zero) await Task.Delay(timeToWait); // Wait with timer

while (DateTime.UtcNow < targetTime); // Spin-wait

Request request = client.sendRequest();
```

Spinning consumes a physical CPU thread, so you should avoid spinning on more threads than the number of physical CPU cores of your machine. A more sophisticated approach would be to dedicate just one [high-priority](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.priority) master thread for spinning, which would control other worker threads by signaling [`ManualResetEventSlim`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.manualreseteventslim) components.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the issue might be related on how you are calculating the time delay for each request.

```
public static async Task<Request> SendRequest(Client client, DateTime startTime, int offset)
{
    DateTime currentTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
    TimeSpan timeToWait = startTime - currentTime + TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(offset);
    
    if (timeToWait.TotalMilliseconds > 0)
        await Task.Delay(timeToWait);
    
    Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("hh:mm:ss.fff")}: {offset}");
    Request request = client.sendRequest();
    return request;
}

async static public Task<Request[]> SendMultiple(Client client, DateTime startTime)
{
    var offsets = new[] { -15, -10 };
    List<Task<Request>> tasks = new List<Task<Request>>();
    
    foreach (var offset in offsets)
    {
        tasks.Add(SendRequest(client, startTime, offset));
    }
    
    Request[] result = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    return result;
}
```

I calculate the current time before calculating the time to wait. Check if the calculated time to wait is negative, meaning that the start time has already passed. In such cases, I don't delay and proceed immediately. Using a `List<Task<Request>>` to collect the tasks for each request and then await `Task.WhenAll` to wait for all requests to complete.

output:

```
08:59:59.985: -15
09:00:00.000: -10
```